# How to creat Dialog PopUp window with custom Layout?

Tags: java, android, dialog, popupwindow

I'm trying to create a dialog popup window with a custom layout, but my custom layout height and popup window height is not matching. Also, the popup window is hiding a button. What should I do, how can I match my popup window height with a custom layout?
Please help me.
**I want my popup window to look like this**

[image: My goal]

**But it is looking like this**

[image]

**My custom layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="336dp"
    android:layout_height="156dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
    android:background="@drawable/rectangle"
    android:layout_marginBottom="88dp">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="58dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/bikepic" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="64dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/delivery" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/biketextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="69dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
    android:background="@drawable/biketextview"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Bike"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/deliverytextView"
    android:layout_width="64dp"
    android:layout_height="18dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="64dp"
    android:background="@drawable/deliverytextview"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Delivery"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView7"
    android:layout_width="23dp"
    android:layout_height="14dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="78dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="74"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView5" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView8"
    android:layout_width="23dp"
    android:layout_height="14dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="80dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="39"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView6" />
```

**popup dialog code**

```
popAddPost = new Dialog(this);
    popAddPost.setContentView(R.layout.pop_up_confirm_pickup);
    //popAddPost.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
    //popAddPost.getWindow().setLayout(Toolbar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,Toolbar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    popAddPost.getWindow().getAttributes().gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;
```

Answer (score 2):

**In your xml, the parent layout is using RelativeLayout LayoutParams on a ConstraintLayout**

Remove `android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"` and `android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"`

ConstraintLayout also doesn't support `layout_gravity` so you can also remove that.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/rectangle"
    android:layout_marginBottom="88dp">
```

**Code**

```
popAddPost = new Dialog(this);
popAddPost.setContentView(R.layout.pop_up_confirm_pickup);
Objects.requireNonNull(popAddPost.getWindow()).setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
popAddPost.show();
```

**EDIT**

To position the dialog at the bottom use this:

```
Window window = popAddPost.getWindow();
WindowManager.LayoutParams params = window.getAttributes();
params.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;
window.setAttributes(params);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how i do it:

```
private AlertDialog alertDialog;
alertDialog = buildDialog();
alertDialog.show();

private AlertDialog buildDialog(){
        final AlertDialog dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog, null);

        dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);

        dialogBuilder.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "CLOSE", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialogBuilder.dismiss();
            }
        });
        return dialogBuilder;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think dialog is not a good solution for your problem as a dialog would have its own window with overlay.

As I can see you want the dialog to be at the bottom of the screen, which makes the **BottomSheet** as a perfect match for your problem.
You can use the following to get started with:

https://www.androidhive.info/2017/12/android-working-with-bottom-sheet/

https://material.io/develop/android/components/bottom-sheet-behavior/

https://medium.com/@droidbyme/android-bottom-sheet-7e9cfcec6427

With **BottomSheet**, you would get a separate window just like dialog without the overlay you are facing.